# My cloth keeps exploding

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I added the cloth physics to a mesh but it looks like its exploding (in pic). Any solution to make it behave normal ?[image: weird cloth sim]

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have collision problems at the start of your animation or the cloth is too small to fit over your mesh - there isn’t enough information in your question to tell for sure. It would be helpful to show the geometry of your cloth (wireframe) at the start of your animation as well as provide details of your cloth settings.

General cloth animation rules apply :

- Always ‘Apply Scale’ to any meshes involved in the simulation
- Disable cloth self collision to rule that out first
- Reduce ‘Outer’ collision distance
- Increase the size of your cloth to ensure not overlapping with collision bounds at the start of the animation
- Check normals to ensure pointing in the correct direction

This should (hopefully) result in a stable simulation and then you can start to tweak the settings one by one to get the desired result. Note that your cloth mesh should typically consist of many evenly sized and evenly proportioned faces as vertex density significantly affects cloth simulation.